# Can I add constructor when using @Builder pattern?

Tags: java, spring-boot, constructor, builder, lombok

I am doing a Spring Boot project and in my domain class, I want to use @Builder annotation from Lombok.
I also need to have a constructor with no parameters to work with my couchbase.

When I added the said constructor I ended up with error;

```
java: constructor Room in class com.trendyol.hotel.domain.Room cannot be applied to given types;required: no argumentsfound:java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,int,int,double,java.lang.String,double,java.util.List<java.util.Date>reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

The said arguments are my fields in the class.
I am filling the fields with default values(for couchbase)

I'm wondering, is there a way to use @Builder and also have a constructor?

Here is my class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class Room {

@NonNull
private String id;
@NonNull
private String hotelId;
@NonNull
private int roomNumber;
private int floor;
private int noOfBeds;
private double m2;
private String view;
private double nightlyPrice;
private List<Date> bookedDates;


public Room() {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    this.hotelId = "hotelId";
    this.roomNumber = 0;
    this.floor = 0;
    this.noOfBeds = 1;
    this.m2 = 10;
    this.view = "default view";
    this.nightlyPrice = 0;
    this.bookedDates = new ArrayList<Date>();
} }
```

Comment: Could you show some code? Are you using, for instance, the `@NoArgsConstructor` annotation?

Comment: ```@Builder @Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor``` should all work together...
add all 4 annotation to the class, and see if error still accrues
Also I know in old lombok version the order of the annotation matters,
try putting the ```@builder``` annotation first

Comment: hi, i added the code of my class